# Firebase get data using key value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an list app with FirebaseListAdapter. I'm having problem with the getKey() value. I want to access the data under the listitem that is been clicked and display it in the textview from another activity. But ican't figure out what to do ?

Here's what my code looks like now

```
   myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Story st = (Story)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String stry = st.Story;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+stry,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyStoryActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Story", stry);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting the story value of the last added story when I clicked on any of the list item.

Here's the code of another activity where I want to display the value of the Story.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.story_view);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("Stories");
    ttl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    stry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    stry1 = bundle.getString("Story");



    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Story ad = dataSnapshot.getValue(Story.class);

                ttl.setText(ad.Title);
                stry.setText(stry1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

This is what my database looks like
[image]

Here is the Story.class

```
public class Story {

public String Title;
public String Story;

// Default constructor required for calls to
// DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
public Story() {
}

public Story(String ttl, String stry) {
    this.Title = ttl;
    this.Story = stry;
}}
```

Comment: show your `Story` class

Comment: @PhátPhát added the stroy.class

Answer (score 0):

Use `Parcelable` for sending object to another `Activity`

Follow this [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable)

Comment: Nah! its still showing the last added story to each item when clicked.

Comment: I just edited the answer. This is not about firebase, you want to communicate between activities

Comment: How does it would gonna help me? coz the Bundle() function is also sending the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Story story = myAdapter.getItem(position);
            String st = story.getStory();
            String tt = story.getTitle();


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyStoryActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Story", st);
            bundle.putString("Title",tt);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

I got the solution by defining the variable of my Story.class to the item position which is been clicked and getting the data by the variable.